# Change server date of SQL server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

My application is using the SQL Server 2008 database and the server is present in a remote machine.

For testing purpose, i want future date in my database.

So please suggest, how can i change the current date to some future date ?

Comment: Change the system clock on the machine hosting your instance?

Comment: I can see how you might want to fake data as if it's from the past, but I can't imagine any scenario where you'd need to deal with data from the future.

Comment: But i cannot access the system clock, i have only access for the database.

Comment: SQL server gets it's time from the system it is running on, changing this is a really bad idea as it will screw up Kerberos authentication for the machine and all sorts of other stuff.

Answer (score 0):

When you run your SQL statement, just add to `GETDATE()` like this:

```
SELECT ..., DATEADD(DAY, 10, GETDATE())
```

That would add 10 days to the current date for example.

Comment: I guess he wants to change it, not just selecting it.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal, if that's the case I'm going to officially put down, that is a ***terrible idea.***

Comment: Yes, i want to change the server date.

Comment: @SnehanjaliSahoo, you actually don't. What you want to do is inject the right date for testing purposes. Changing the server date will only raise your risk surrounding production deployment and such. I know it seems like more work, and it is in a way, but it's the right way to do it.